# OCaml - exceptions

Tags: exception, ocaml

I have a code with an exception for when 1<=a<=30 and 1<=b<=n

I have:

```
exception invalid_input

let n = 5

let k = 6

if n<1 || n > 30 || k<1 || k>n  then raise Invalid_input
else ()
```

But the compiler says Syntax error in the line with the if then else.
What is wrong?

Comment: The only error I see is in the first line, it must be `exception Invalid_input` with an uppercase `I`. Also you inverted your tests, why `n < 1` and not `n >= 1`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing expressions and definitions.
The idiomatic way to compute an effectful expression after some definitions is
to use `let () = ...`:

```
let () = if n<1 || n > 30 || k<1 || k>n  then raise Invalid_input
```

Otherwise, you can separate this expression from the definitions above with `;;`

```
;; if n<1 || n > 30 || k<1 || k>n  then raise Invalid_input
```